# PHP Excel Reader - Writing Tables

Tags: php, excel

Hey guys i am new to PHP and is trying to self learn this language. Right now i am trying to implement something using pure PHP to display Excel documents onto browsers. I am using PHP Excel Reader to read the documents but somehow they are not showing.

Although i can do my own debugging and research if there were error messages which tells me which line was causing the error, but there were none and the problem i am facing now is that

1. The tables are not showing up
2. No error messages of any kind from apache

What i am trying to achieve:

- Display Excel spreadsheets in table format on browsers using PHP Excel Reader
- Check how many sheets are in the .xls document, get the sheet name and display the amount of buttons accordingly
- The buttons must be able to allow the user to traverse between different sheets of one document

Right now i am able to get the codes to count the number of sheets and display its name and buttons correctly, but still not being able to display the corresponding tables.

I have tried many ways to tackle this issue based on the documentation but to no avail.

Here are my current codes:

example.php

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    require_once 'reader.php';
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/excel.js"></script>
    <style>
    table.excel {
            border-style:ridge;
            border-width:1;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            font-family:sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
    }
    table.excel thead th, table.excel tbody th {
            background:#CCCCCC;
            border-style:ridge;
            border-width:1;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    table.excel tbody th {
            text-align:center;
            width:20px;
    }
    table.excel tbody td {
            vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    .clearfloat {
            clear: both;
    }
    table.excel tbody td {
        padding: 0 3px;
            border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    }
    table.excel tname {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000000;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
    }
    .sheetnames {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000000;
            padding-right: 20px;
            float: left;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="changeSheet(0)">
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="worksheet">
    <?php
    $i = -1;
    for($s=0; $s<count($data->sheets)-1; $s++) {
    $i++;
    ?>
    <div class="sheetnames">
    <input name="sheet" type="button" value="<?php echo $data->boundsheets[$i]['name'];?>" onClick="changeSheet(<?php echo $i ?>)">
    </div>
    <?php

}
?>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

excel.js

```
// JavaScript Document
var xmlHttp 

function changeSheet(n)
{ 
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
if (xmlHttp==null)
 {
 alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
 return
 }
var url="script pages/changeSheet.php"
url=url+"?q="+n
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
}

function stateChanged() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
 { 
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText 
 } 
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
 {
 // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
 xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e)
 {
 //Internet Explorer
 try
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
 catch (e)
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

changeSheet.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls");

$q = $_GET['q'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $data->dump(true,false, $sheet=$q); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And attached along with the codes is the library file for PHP Excel Reader which i do not believe is causing the problem.

Once again, i thank you guys for taking time to read my question. So what went wrong? What was causing the tables to not show up?

Comment: What happens when you invoke changeSheet.php from your browser?

Comment: Sorry i am new but if you meant running it i will get an error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader::dump() in ..\phpExcelReader\Excel\changesheet.php on line 16"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your version of Excel_Reader does not support "::dump()".

Looks like you have to iterate through the sheets, rows and columns yourself.

Try var_dump($data) to see whats in there.

Comment: Sorry i did not get your answer in full. Do you mean doing a while-echo printing based on column and rows? Do you mind elaborating?